# Is there an equivalent of mount -a for cryptsetup?

Tags: mount, cryptsetup

`mount -a` will ensure everything in `/etc/fstab` is mounted (except for `noauto` entries). Is there an equivalent for cryptsetup, which will unlock everything in `/etc/crypttab`?

Answer (score 2):

No, not on current Debian Jessie Systems.

Reading the functions called from `/etc/init.d/cryptsetup` (/lib/cryptsetup/cryptdisk.functions), I can see, that the init-script uses `egrep` and `read` to read individual lines, which are then processed further (= mounted) by the script.

This result will most likely apply to all current Linux distributions.